# Why is my Div Only printed twice?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How come my div is not printing for as many times as it loops?
I want the picture to be displayed 10 times and for some reason is is only showing up twice. Any ideas, all help is welcome and appreciated. Thanks!

I select the Div, I clone it, and now I want to display it 10 times.

```js
var stuffIWantRepeated = document.getElementsByTagName("DIV")[0];
var clone = stuffIWantRepeated.cloneNode(true);

for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  document.body.appendChild(clone);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>

  <style>
    #maindiv img {
      border-bottom-color: black;
      display: block;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }
    #maindiv {
      padding-top: 10%;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="maindiv">
    <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/571024672750178304/GpGC8aTW.jpeg" border="40">
  </div>


</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to clone once for each time you want to append it. A particular node can only be in the DOM in one place.

Just move that line into the loop:

```
for(var i = 1; i <=  10; i++) {
    var clone = stuffIWantRepeated.cloneNode(true);
    document.body.appendChild(clone);
}
```

Comment: Minor error - this will result in 12 images. OP only wanted 10.

Comment: @vivekmaharajh well it's not clear to me what the OP wants, but surely adjusting the iteration count as desired should be a small matter.

Answer (score 0):

```html
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>

  <style>
    #maindiv img {
      border-bottom-color: black;
      display: block;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }
    #maindiv {
      padding-top: 10%;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="maindiv">
    <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/571024672750178304/GpGC8aTW.jpeg" border="40">
  </div>


</body>

<script>
      var stuffIWantRepeated = document.getElementsByTagName("DIV")[0];
  for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    var clone = stuffIWantRepeated.cloneNode(true);
    document.body.appendChild(clone);
  }
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: seems like I was a little slower than Pointy..hee hee

Answer (score 0):

Rather than creating a clone and appending it ten times over, you should create ten clones and append each individually:

Replace:

```
<script>
var stuffIWantRepeated = document.getElementsByTagName("DIV")[0];
var clone = stuffIWantRepeated.cloneNode(true);

for(var i = 1; i <=  10; i++) {
    document.body.appendChild(clone);
}
</script>
```

With this:

```
<script>
var stuffIWantRepeated = document.getElementsByTagName("DIV")[0];

for(var i = 1; i <=  10; i++) {
    var clone = stuffIWantRepeated.cloneNode(true);
    document.body.appendChild(clone);
}
</script>
```

For example: https://jsfiddle.net/40wukrta/

Answer (score 0):

You need to clone it every time in your loop. Once appended into the document, the clone will get invalid.

```js
var stuffIWantRepeated = document.querySelectorAll("DIV")[0];

for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  var clone = stuffIWantRepeated.cloneNode(true);
  document.body.appendChild(clone);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>

  <style>
    #maindiv img {
      border-bottom-color: black;
      display: block;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }
    #maindiv {
      padding-top: 10%;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="maindiv">
    <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/571024672750178304/GpGC8aTW.jpeg" border="40">
  </div>


</body>


</html>
```